# Spring MVC request mapping conflict

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, mapping

I'm having an issue regarding @RequestMapping on classes. Say I have these two controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/controller1")
public class Controller1 {

    @RequestMapping(value="/method11.do")
    public @ResponseBody method11(){
            //...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/method12.do")
    public ModelAndView method12(){
            //This method redirects me to another jsp where I'll call Controller2 methods
            return new ModelAndView("test");

    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/controller2")
public class Controller2 {

    @RequestMapping(value="/method21.do")
    public @ResponseBody method21(){
            //...
    }

}
```

When I first call via AJAX method11, it works fine, the url generated is `http://mydomain/myapp/controller1/method11.do`

Then, I call method12 and get redirected to test.jsp, and from there, I call to method21, and here is the problem, the url generated is not the expected `http://mydomain/myapp/controller2/method21.do`, but something else, depending on how I make the AJAX call:

```
url:'controller2/method21' --> http://mydomain/myapp/controller1/controller2/method21.do
url:'/controller2/method21' --> http://mydomain/controller2/method21.do
```

So, in what way should I make the calls so that they always start at `http://mydomain/myapp/...`?

I believe I could just use `url:'/myapp/controller2/method21.do'`, but I guess there should be a more generic way in which I don't have to use 'myapp' on every call.

This is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: In `jsp`, you can use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`. So `url:'/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller2/method21`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the client aware of the proper URL by retrieving the context root within your script using JSP EL.

**In JSP**

```
<script>var ctx = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"</script>
```

You can then use `ctx` as a prefix to the URLs constructed via Javascript.

```
var url = ctx + "/rest_of_url"
```

On the server side, you can use:

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}` or JSTL has a tag, `<c:url>` which will append your context root.

Comment: Thanks! This has worked fine. Also, I wanted to ask, is this the proper way to accomplish this or is there some other more elegant or convinient? Maybe through web.xml or spring-servlet.xml

Comment: @carcaret I'm not aware of a more elegant solution, I use this method on my blog where the context root changes between environments.  This article discusses the problem in regards to static resources: http://www.sivalabs.in/2011/07/context-root-relative-urls-using.html